# How to find a path that goes through all points of a 2d graph while alternating between X axis and Y axis

Tags: point, algorithm, graph, path

I know my title isn't very descriptive, i'll try to explain it better here.

Let's say I have a list of coordinates that is built as the following :

list = [ (0,0) , (1,0) , (0,1) , (1,1) , (2,0) ]

The graph looks like this

[image: graph of coordinates in list]

I want to be able to find a path that goes through all points while alternating between points on the X axis and points on the Y axis and going only ONCE on each point.

If I chose any first point on the graph and a second point on the same X axis as the first point, the third point should be on the same Y axis, and the fourth on the same X axis again, and the fifth on the same Y axis, so on...

The same applies if the first and second point are on the same Y axis, the third point would be on the same X axis as the second one.

So if we reuse the previous graph, 2 possible ways are as the following:

[image: first possible way]

(2,0),(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)

[image: second possible way]

(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(0,0),(2,0)

(maybe there are more ways)

So what I've found so far is that :

- there should not be a point that is the only point on its X axis AND Y axis
- there should only be a MAXIMUM of 2 points which are the only point on its X axis OR Y axis (not both)

Since each point should be served only once, this is not a TSP problem, since the path should not end where it started.

Are there any algorithms to help me, or do you have any ideas on how I might achieve this ?

I have only found conditions for it to work

Comment: What if there is no point left with the same x or y coordinate of the previous point?

Comment: well the algorithm should go back 2 points behind, and try again for other sets of points, and if ultimately no solution is found, then there are no possible paths

Comment: You can formulate the problem mathematically: from a list of features with x-/y-coordinate values, can you create an order so that you get the coordinate values of the next feature by alternating adding/subtracting a value from only the x-, then only the y-value. So this is a pure mathematical problem and not necessarily a spatial one.

Comment: Depending on how many points you have, a raw, brute force approache of testing all possible combinations would be a workaround